# Bayes Theorem with multiple random variables

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I came across this expression in the Intro to Probability book I am studying:

$P(A,B|C)=\frac{P(C)P(B|C)P(A|B,C)}{P(C)}$

Could anyone please explain how is this obtained. From a simple application of Bayes Rule, shouldn't it be:

$P(A,B|C)=\frac{P(C|A,B)P(A,B)}{P(C)}$ where $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ ?

Comment: Is $P(A,B|C)=\frac{P(C)P(B|C)P(A|B,C)}{P(C)}$ correct? As the $P(C)$ just cancels.

Comment: Yep, it is. They cancel out the $P(C)$ and write $P(B|C)P(A|B,C)$ as the final expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of conditional probability: $P(Y \mid X)=P(X,Y)/P(X) \implies P(X,Y)=P(Y\mid X) P(X)$. Hence (think of $A,B$ as a single multivariate variable):

$$P(A,B\mid C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)}$$

Then, by the chain rule of probability, $P(A,B,C)=P(A\mid B,C)P(B,C)$ and $P(B,C)=P(B\mid C)P(C)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't ${P(Y|X) = P(X,Y)|P(X)}$ according to Bayes' rule? I do understand now how the answer was obtained, so its just a different way of interpreting the $P(A,B,C)$? The way how $P(A,B,C)$ was split into $P(A|B,C)P(B,C)$ instead of $P(C|A,B)P(A,B)$. Are both of them equivalent?

Comment: Error fixed. Yes, both forms are equivalent

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Bayes' rule

Comment: @ovolve why not?

Comment: @leonbloy Does our choice of splitting usually depend on the problem at hand, or is there sometimes a specific rule by which we can go about it? Would you know of something that we can keep in mind, any sort of hint or direction by which we can go about choosing our splitting?

Comment: @QPTR Bayes' rule says $P(A,B|C)=\frac{P(C|A,B)P(A,B)}{P(C)}$. It looks close to what you are given, but the difference is in your problem $C$ is never conditioned on $A,B$. You can get your derivation with just the definition of conditional probability and the chain rule. Flipping things with Bayes doesn't help

Comment: @QTPR Yes, you can choose what you condition on, and in practice it will be obvious how you should do it because you'll want to condition on the thing that you know!

Comment: @ovolve Ah, right, true, thanks for that explanation. I'll do more questions on it to practice the choosing part.

Answer (score 0):

The extension of Baye's rule is such that $$P(A,B|C)=\frac{\color{blue}{P(A)}\color{blue}{P(B|A)}P(C|A,B)}{\color{blue}{P(B)}P(C|B)}\tag{1}$$

The formula can be seen as an extension of $$P(A|B)=\frac{\color{blue}{P(A)P(B|A)}}{\color{blue}{P(B)}}\tag{2}$$ This is not a derivation of course; I'm just trying to show you that the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ terms are common to both $(1)$ and $(2)$ and if you reverse the conditioning for the extra variable ($C$) by placing the conditional probabilities in both numerator and denominator you arrive at $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't understand $(1)$. From my understanding it seems like there should only be $P(C)$ in the denominator. How was $P(B)P(C|B)$ obtained?

Comment: @QPTR See this [link](https://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/local_copies_of_sources_Cardinal_and_Aitken_ANOVA/Bayes_theorem.htm) under section $3.3$ for more info, hope this helps.

Comment: @QPTR You're absolutely right, my mistake sorry it was a typo.

Comment: @QPTR I'm curious; Do you have a source by any chance for your formula in your question? As I have never seen it written like that before. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, its [this](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Dimitri-P-Bertsekas/dp/188652940X) one, Intro to Prob by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis. Here's the [pdf](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~jason777/School/introduction%20to%20probability%20(bertsekas,%202nd,%202008).pdf). Its under the Conditional Independence heading on Page 36.

Comment: @QPTR Thanks! I appreciate that :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)